# $1 \leq a^2x^2 + b^2y^2 - abxy \leq 9 , x\geq 1$- question compactness and connectedness..

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness, analytic-geometry, connectedness

I was told that this object was a cone, I cannot see that, can anyone tell me how to identify which object this is, so as to continue assesing and answering questions of compactness and connectedness..

Comment: when you have a quadratic you may transform it into sum of squares: the inequality in the question is equivalent to $$1 \leq \left(ax-\frac{by}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}(by)^2\leq 9$$ and this proves that your object is the  the set of points between two ellipses

Comment: Two similar ellipses with the same centre, differing only by an identical scaling of the minor and major axes. @Jerry: A cone is a three-dimensional figure; your inequalities are two-dimensional (if we assume that $a$ and $b$ play their traditional role of parameters and $x$ and $y$ play they traditional role of coordinates, as we must, since you didn't introduce them). Perhaps you mean conic sections?

Comment: I agree, but how do I conclude from the inequality above that elipses are in question, after tranformations? I still cant see that.

Comment: Same here. ${}{}{}{}{}$